# wss4j: - Cannot find key for alias: monit

Tags: java, certificate, wss4j

When I define (using axis 1.4 an wss4j) in client-config.wsdd for WSDoAllSender and WSDoAllReceiver different signaturePropFiles where I have different key stores defined with different certificates, I'm able to have different certificates for sending and receiving. But when I use the same signaturePropFiles' with the same keystore. I get this message when I try to send a message:

```
  org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.CryptoBase -- Cannot find key for alias: [monit] in keystore of type [jks] from provider [SUN version 1.5] with size [2] and aliases: {other, monit}
- Error during Signature: ; nested exception is:
        org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: Signature creation failed; nested exception is:
        java.lang.Exception: Cannot find key for alias: [monit]
org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: Error during Signature: ; nested exception is:
        org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: Signature creation failed; nested exception is:
        java.lang.Exception: Cannot find key for alias: [monit]
        at org.apache.ws.security.action.SignatureAction.execute(SignatureAction.java:60)
        at org.apache.ws.security.handler.WSHandler.doSenderAction(WSHandler.java:202)
        at org.apache.ws.axis.security.WSDoAllSender.invoke(WSDoAllSender.java:168)
        at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
        at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
        at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
        at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:127)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
        at cz.xxx.opf.model.wsclient.ModelWebServiceSoapBindingStub.getStatus(ModelWebServiceSoapBindingStub.java:213)
        at cz.xxx.opf.wsgemonitor.monitor.util.MonitorUtil.checkStatus(MonitorUtil.java:18)
        at cz.xxx.opf.wsgemonitor.monitor.Test02WsMonitor.runTest(Test02WsMonitor.java:23)
        at cz.xxx.opf.wsgemonitor.Main.main(Main.java:75)
Caused by: org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: Signature creation failed; nested exception is:
        java.lang.Exception: Cannot find key for alias: [monit]
        at org.apache.ws.security.message.WSSecSignature.computeSignature(WSSecSignature.java:721)
        at org.apache.ws.security.message.WSSecSignature.build(WSSecSignature.java:780)
        at org.apache.ws.security.action.SignatureAction.execute(SignatureAction.java:57)
        ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Cannot find key for alias: [monit]
        at org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.CryptoBase.getPrivateKey(CryptoBase.java:214)
        at org.apache.ws.security.message.WSSecSignature.computeSignature(WSSecSignature.java:713)
        ... 17 more
```

How to have two certificates for wss4j in the same keystore? why it cannot find my certificate there when i have two certificates in one keystore.

I have the same password for both certificates regarding PWCallback (CallbackHandler)

My properties file:

```
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.provider=org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin 
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.type=jks
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.password=keystore
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.alias=monit
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.alias.password=***
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.file=key.jks
```

My client-config.wsdd:

```
  <deployment xmlns="http://xml.apache.org/axis/wsdd/" xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/axis/wsdd/providers/java">
 <globalConfiguration>  
  <requestFlow>
   <handler name="WSSecurity" type="java:org.apache.ws.axis.security.WSDoAllSender">
        <parameter name="user" value="monit"/>
        <parameter name="passwordCallbackClass" value="cz.xxx.opf.common.ws.PWCallback"/>
        <parameter name="action" value="Signature"/>
        <parameter name="signaturePropFile" value="monit.properties"/>
        <parameter name="signatureKeyIdentifier" value="DirectReference" />
        <parameter name="mustUnderstand" value="0"/>
   </handler>
     <handler type="java:org.apache.axis.handlers.JWSHandler">
        <parameter name="scope" value="session"/>
     </handler>
     <handler type="java:org.apache.axis.handlers.JWSHandler">
        <parameter name="scope" value="request"/>
        <parameter name="extension" value=".jwr"/>
     </handler>
   </requestFlow>
   <responseFlow>  
        <handler name="DoSecurityReceiver" type="java:org.apache.ws.axis.security.WSDoAllReceiver">
            <parameter name="user" value="other"/>  
            <parameter name="passwordCallbackClass" value="cz.xxx.opf.common.ws.PWCallback"/>
            <parameter name="action" value="Signature"/>
            <parameter name="signaturePropFile" value="other.properties"/>
            <parameter name="signatureKeyIdentifier" value="DirectReference" />  
        </handler>  
   </responseFlow>

 </globalConfiguration>

 <transport name="http" pivot="java:org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender">  

 </transport>
</deployment>
```

Listing from keytool:
keytool -keystore monit-key.jks -v -list

```
Enter keystore password:

Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 2 entries

Alias name: other
Creation date: Jul 22, 2009
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
....

Alias name: monit
Creation date: Oct 19, 2009
Entry type: trustedCertEntry
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved that months ago and if any one need it. problem was that I didn't have private key in keystore.

Comment: you have already given org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.alias.password=*** \n what exactly you mean private key in Keystore?

Comment: It wasn't related to org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.alias.password property at all. Just as I wrote the private key wasn't in the key store. In order to sign a message you need sender's private key. There was only public key in the key store. As you can see above from listing (keytool -keystore monit-key.jks -v -list). Entry type of related key(monit) is trustedCertEntry, which I suppose is only stored certificate with public key. Which is important only the public key was in the key store.

Comment: Thanks @feiroox for your clarification. Looks like you can clarify my question here. I got struck with the similar issue. I got the certificate from the Client and I imported that one into my KeyStore(myKey.jks) file with alias name as "mykey". Its an "trustedCertEntry" when I list JKS file.But When I try to use that alias name in my configuration which I implemented with Apache CXF & WSS4J, its giving me an error --> Cannot find key for alias: [mykey]. SO HOW TO  ADD or GENERATE KEY(Assuming tha Public Key) for the Given Certificate or KeyStore(mykey.jks)?? Appreciate your response..

Comment: Btw, I followed this URL below to implement Digital Signature with WSS4J --> https://sites.google.com/site/ddmwsst/ws-security-impl

Comment: I'm sorry I haven't been here. It's better to ask a question on the stackoverflow.com . If I am wrong or don't have time someone else might help you and it can serve others as well. But I guess you have already figured it out by now.

Answer (score 1):

I was using Sun's jdk which was giving a problem when I changed it to IBM JDK then problem went away